# Finding an element in another element by Xpath

Tags: javascript, protractor, webdriver

I'm writing some e2e using XPath (for various reasons I can't set sweet IDs on my the project). Yet, when finding a parent element via XPath and subsequently trying to find a child in it, Protractor ignores the parent element and tries to find it in the whole document.

(This is a situation where various checkboxes share the same name, but they're contained in different cards that can act as parents.)

I've tested the XPath expressions individually, and they find the element I want, I've also joined the XPath expressions and they work perfectly, what I don't understand Is why is in not working when running it in Protractor.

This function finds the Parent element

```
findEpCard(label:string) {
        //return element(by.xpath('//ep-card//div[contains(@class, "ep-card-header")]//h4[text() = "'+label+'"]/../..'));
        return element(by.xpath('//ep-card[.//h4[text() = "'+label+'"]]'));
    }
```

This is the function that finds a checkbox by searching the parent card

```
findCheckbox(parentCard: string, label: string) {
        let card =  this.findEpCard(parentCard)
        return card.element(by.xpath('//ep-check-box[.//span[text()="'+label+'"]]'));
    }
```

But when calling it with

```
csKeyField = this.findCheckbox('Control Settings','Key Field');
```

it will find all the Checkboxes in the DOM.

Searching by joining the 2 xpaths works perfectly, but I am trying to avoid it:

```
return element(by.xpath('//ep-card[.//h4[text() = "'+parentCard+'"]]//ep-check-box[.//span[text()="'+label+'"]]'));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `.` at the heading of following xpath, `.` at here means search element start from current node which is the parent node.  Without `.` at here your xpath tells browser to search element start from the beginning of the HTML.

`card.element(by.xpath('.//ep-check-box[.//span[text()="'+label+'"]]'));`

Comment: This XPath is not doing what you think it is doing.  Selenium is not totally compliant to XPath specs and it doesn't treat // as descendant-or-self.  Instead it searches the whole DOM.  So what you are really doing is `//span[text()="'+label+'"]`. you will need to explicitly change // too `descendant-or-self::` to get the behaviour you think you are getting